# Is it possible to map custom smart contracts to Ethereum?

Tags: erc-20, evm, bridge

We need snapshots (Snapshots allow to lock user's balances to prevent multiple votes with same tokens https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/3.x/api/token/erc20#ERC20Snapshot) in the token smart contract deployed on Aurora. Could we deploy our own custom token smart contract on Aurora and map it to a token on Ethereum?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to map custom smart contracts to Ethereum. Any Ethereum ERC-20 can be bridged to Aurora, there are no restrictions. However, deploying your own custom token smart contracts on Aurora and mapping it to a token on Ethereum cannot be done directly with the recent update.

Aurora bridge works the following way: if a user wants to bridge the token from Ethereum (let’s call it ERC-20) to Aurora (let’s call it aERC-20), then they need to:

- Check that aERC-20 is already deployed to Aurora. If not, then a user should issue a specific transaction for deployment of aERC-20. This transaction includes the address of the ERC-20 so that Aurora can store the mapping. This transaction is called only once. The aERC-20 is a standard vanilla OpenZepplin ERC-20 with minor updates to allow bridging: https://github.com/aurora-is-near/aurora-engine/blob/master/etc/eth-contracts/contracts/EvmErc20.sol
- Once done, the user is able to bridge ERC-20 into aERC-20. The transfer requires two transactions on Ethereum side (`approve` and lock, which calls `transferFrom`), and one transaction on NEAR side (which is issued automatically by our relayer).
  As you see, the aERC-20 contract is fixed. So it doesn’t have any specific methods or anything. After the deployment any contract can put special clauses based on the aERC-20 address. This is the way you need to interact with bridge tokens at the moment.
  There is a discussion whether Aurora will allow projects to do the following thing:
- Deploy their Aurora token (pERC-20)
- Change the mapping ERC-20 -> aERC-20, so it’s mapped to a custom implementation of the token: ERC-20 -> pERC-20
- Migrate the tokens from aERC-20 to pERC-20.